как реализовать уведомления по времени через WorkManager Android
Нужно сделать уведомления, которые будут отправляться в определенное время в течении дня.
Например в 10:00, в 12:00, в 15:00 должны отправиться уведомления
Как это реализовать через WorkManager или AlarmManager, так что бы он не нагружал систему?
Пробовал сделать через AlarmManager, но уведомления не приходят:
Класс отвечающий за отправку и создание уведомлений:
public class NotificationScheduler extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "notification_channel";
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        createNotification(context);
    }

    public void setRepeatingAlarms(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        long time10am = getTimeInMillis(10, 0);  
        long time12pm = getTimeInMillis(12, 0);  
        long time3pm = getTimeInMillis(15, 0); 

        setAlarm(context, alarmManager, time10am);
        setAlarm(context, alarmManager, time12pm);
        setAlarm(context, alarmManager, time3pm);
    }

    private void setAlarm(Context context, AlarmManager alarmManager, long triggerAtMillis) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationScheduler.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, pendingIntent);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, pendingIntent);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint({"MissingPermission", "NotificationPermission"})
    private void createNotification(Context context) {
        
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "name";
            String description = "disc";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
                .setContentText("Текст!")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

     
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }

    private long getTimeInMillis(int hour, int minute) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }

}

В onCreate:
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
        Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
        v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
        return insets;
    });

    NotificationScheduler scheduler = new NotificationScheduler();
    scheduler.setRepeatingAlarms(this);
}


Через Alarm Manager это реализуется.

@Style-7, так опишите как это реализовать

Напишите что вы уже сделали и что не так работает. Иначе похоже что ищете чтобы кто-то писал код за вас. Уже есть ChatGPT для этого.

И да, WorkManager написан на Котлин :)

@EugeneKrivenja, добавил в вопрос, что пробовал

Почитайте мой ответ

@Eugene Krivenja , Alarm Manager source code

@Style-7, WorkManager source code
